# Bash script to switch to root user with password (no additional libraries like expect can be used)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

`su`
`Enter Password: abcd`
I need to be able to do the above process through a shell script. The issue is that it needs to be done with only the basic set of libraries that are available. No additional libraries can be used (eg except). Kindly do not suggest the usage of "sudo" or other things, this is the exact thing I need to do.
I have tried the following:
`echo "abcd" | su`
But it still ends up asking for the password again.

Comment: is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19954540/2987755?

Comment: @dkb The solution uses expect tool which I mentioned cannot be used for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You should try NOPASSWD option. Use it for the particular command which you are going to execute for security reasons. [Here](https://bitmingw.com/2017/01/22/use-sudo-in-scripts/) are two methods explained but i think second one is what exactly you need.

Comment: The second method required me to edit the etc/sudoers which again cannot be done for my case.

Comment: Then while running the script you will have to enter the password once atleast every time, then for the rest of execution in the bash script it can be cached for predefined time.

Comment: The system is a 32-bit Fedora based Linux. The expect library is only available for a 64-bit Fedora. Is there any way to recompile the library for 32-bit?